# Espresso Assertion Failed With Cause Error

Tags: unit-testing, android-testing, android-espresso

I have been trying to run a test on espresso, which will give input to editText and will hit a button and then it goes for validation, I have included dependencies tried clearing cache but still facing this error

Here is the test

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class Espresso {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void lenCheck() {
        String text = "short";
        onView(withId(R.id.editText )).perform(typeText(text), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click()) ;
        onView(withId(R.id.textView)).check(matches(withText("Min 8 characters.")));
           }}
```

which gives me following error

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with text: is "Min 8 characters."' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with text: is "Min 8 characters."
Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131165303, res-name=textView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=53, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@e24ffa2, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=602.0, y=1359.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

Is this something related to android studio or framework?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Espresso documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#hasErrorText(java.lang.String)), the following check should work:

```
onView(withId(R.id.textView)).check(matches(hasErrorText("Min 8 characters.")));
```